# Validating String While Loop java No Regex

Tags: java, while-loop

Basically I'm trying to have a few while loops check specific indices within a string. The first loop that validates the length of the refNum works fine. When it gets to the bigger set of while loops it just skips it and I'm not sure why, any feed back would be greatly appreciated.

```
package testing_code;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author A.Con
 */
public class Testing_Code
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
        String refNum;

        System.out.println("Enter refNum: example - WE123A");
        refNum = userInput.next();

        int rnLength = refNum.length();

        while(rnLength < 6 || rnLength > 6)
        {
           System.out.println("Invalid reference number. Try again.\n ");
           System.out.println("Please enter reference No.:  ");
           refNum = userInput.next();
           rnLength = refNum.length();
        }


        while(!(refNum.charAt(0) >= 'A') && !(refNum.charAt(0) <= 'Z') && !(refNum.charAt(1) >= 'A') && !(refNum.charAt(1) <= 'Z')) 
        { 
            while(!(refNum.charAt(2) >= '0') && !(refNum.charAt(2) <= '9') && !(refNum.charAt(3) >= '0') && !(refNum.charAt(3) <= '9')) 
              {
                  while(!(refNum.charAt(4) >= '0') && !(refNum.charAt(4) <= '9') && !(refNum.charAt(5) >= 'A') && !(refNum.charAt(5) <= 'Z'))
                  {
                System.out.println("Invalid reference number. Try again.\n ");
                System.out.println("Please enter reference No.:  ");
                refNum = userInput.next();                    
                  }
              }
        }
```

Comment: Those inner loops doesn't look weel. Supporse the first condition is true and in the inner one is false. `userInput.nezt()` will never be called. Do you follow me?

Comment: Why can't you use regex ? They re here for a reason.

Comment: The course I'm on wants to teach the foundation of java, so they don't teach us regex till 2nd year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` conditions are all wrong. `!(refNum.charAt(0) >= 'A') && !(refNum.charAt(0) <= 'Z')` for instance checks if a character is lower than `A` *and* higher than `Z`, which is impossible; you should be using `or` instead.

As a matter of fact, there are a *lot* of ways you can improve this. Here's my version

```java
public class Testing_Code
{
    static boolean inRange(char c, char first, char last) {
        return (c >= first) && (c <= last);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
        String refNum;

        System.out.println("Enter refNum: example - WE123A");
        refNum = userInput.next();

        while(refnum.length() != 6 
                || !inRange(refnum.charAt(0), 'A', 'Z') 
                || !inRange(refnum.charAt(1), 'A', 'Z') 
                || !inRange(refnum.charAt(2), '0', '9') 
                || !inRange(refnum.charAt(3), '0', '9') 
                || !inRange(refnum.charAt(4), '0', '9') 
                || !inRange(refnum.charAt(5), 'A', 'Z'))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid reference number. Try again.\n ");
            System.out.println("Please enter reference No.:  ");
            refNum = userInput.next();
            rnLength = refNum.length();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First `!(A >= B)` is equivalent to `(A < B)`. So `!(refNum.charAt(0) >= 'A') && !(refNum.charAt(0) <= 'Z')` is equivalent to `(refNum.charAt(0) < 'A') && (refNum.charAt(0) > 'Z')`.

If you look at the ASCII [table](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii%20table&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS732US732&tbm=isch&imgil=2U31hF4tTw886M%253A%253BJMtOixefP_tDJM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.asciitable.com%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=2U31hF4tTw886M%253A%252CJMtOixefP_tDJM%252C_&usg=__v-tVMaZvqb9Q_RD93Q9sEftM8Zg%3D&biw=1920&bih=950&ved=0ahUKEwjB4M_ZvtHUAhVI6iYKHVsnA_cQyjcINA&ei=57xLWYHRIMjUmwHbzoy4Dw#imgrc=2U31hF4tTw886M:), you will see that "less than A and greater than Z" are mutually exclusive conditions. They will never both be true at the same time, so the while loop ends up simplifying to `while(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `while(!refNum.charAt(0) >= 'A') && !(refNum.charAt(0) <= 'Z'))` is always false, as a char can't be less than `'A'` and greater than `'Z'` at same time. Use a `||` instead of `&&` and you are good to go.

I will recommend using

```
Character.isLetter(refNum.charAt(0)) // returns true if the passed character is a letter
Character.isDigit(refNum.charAt(0)) // returns true, if the passed character is a digit.
```

Much simpler & easy to read.